# Most non-greedy regex match in python (or just simply regex in general

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching, non-greedy

Im having an issue where my regex is matching too much.  I've tried making it as non-greedy as possible.  My RE is:

```
 define host( |\t)*{(.*\n)*?( |\t)*host_name( |\t)*HOST_B(.*\n)*?( |\t)*}
```

meaning

> "define host" followed by any spaces or tabs followed by "{".  Any text and newlines until any number of spaces or tabs followed by "host_name" followed by any number of spaces or tabs followed by "HOST_B".  Any text plus newlines until any spaces or tabs followed by "}"

My text is

```
define host{
    field stuff
        }

define timeperiod{
        sunday          00:00-03:00,07:00-24:00
        }

define stuff{
        hostgroup_name                  things
        service_description             load
        dependent_service_description   cpu_util
        execution_failure_criteria      n
        notification_failure_criteria   w,u,c
        }

define host{
        use                     things
        host_name               HOST_A
        0alias                  stuff 
       }

define host{
        use                     things
        host_name               HOST_B
        alias                   ughj
        address                 1.6.7.6
       }

define host{
        use                     things
        host_name               HOST_C
       }
```

The match is going from the first define to host_b's end bracket.  It is not getting host_c's group (it should not get host_c), however I would like only host b's group and not the whole thing.

Any help?  My regex is rusty.  You can test on http://regexpal.com/

Comment: Your format is not regex friendly; you really want to use a parser instead. I'd use `pyparsing` for this task.

Comment: Im doing a few finds and replaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested it, but I guess you need to remove .* with [^{]*. This way your regex does not eat the next "{".

This looks strange to me: `(.*\n)*?`
Have a look at DOTALL: If you set this flag the dot eats newlines.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit different than what you asked for, but I think you may like the results.  This will parse all your structures and load them into python dictionaries.  From there, manipulation should be really nice and easy for you.

```
mDefHost = re.findall(r"\define host{(.*?)\}",a,re.S)
mInHost  = re.compile("(\S+)\s+(\S+)")
hostDefs = []

for item in mDefHost:
    hostDefs.append( dict(mInHost.findall(item)) )
```

ex output

```
>>> m = re.findall(r"define host\{(.*?)\}",a,re.S)
>>> m
['\n        use                     things\n        host_name               HOST_B\n            alias                   ughj\n        address                 1.6.7.6\n       ']
>>> item = m[0]
>>> item
'\n        use                     things\n        host_name               HOST_B\n            alias                   ughj\n        address                 1.6.7.6\n       '
>>> results = re.findall("(\S+)\s+(\S+)",item)
>>> results
[('use', 'things'), ('host_name', 'HOST_B'), ('alias', 'ughj'), ('address', '1.6.7.6')]
>>> dict(results)
{'alias': 'ughj', 'use': 'things', 'host_name': 'HOST_B', 'address': '1.6.7.6'}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using regex to search the entire string, but you're trying to find a substring that starts in a way indistinguishable from the start of the entire string. You can't use *non-greedy matching* to ensure that your *starting* point is as late as possible; the non-greedy modifier *only* affects how far *ahead* the Regex engine will look to find a match.

What you need is to make sure that you have no closing brackets between your `define host` and your `HOST_B`. Try this (untested):

`define host\s*{[^}]HOST_B.*?}`

(Make sure you use a flag to allow `.` to match newlines.)